# how to customize google map for own site?

Tags: google-maps, customization

i want to create google map for own site.my task is that i have to fetch some information from database and i want to show in google map,with my icon.some thing like

"[http://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/Groningen/*/*/*/*/1/?rad=5km&min=450000&max=1000000](http://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/Groningen/_/_/_/_/1/?rad=5km&min=450000&max=1000000)"

in right side ,google map is showing,excatly i want to show my google map.if any have idea please help me

Thanks
Manish
manish.choudhary63@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use google maps api: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Comment: hello...
Thanks for quick reply...but i want to add more place in google map which will come through database . same like my reference site.i have already use google map api and amp is showing,i am also able to pass single value and it is working,my task is create google map with multiple value...pleasetake a look my reference site once 
" http://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/Groningen/_/_/_/_/1/?rad=5km&min=450000&max=1000000 "
and give me another suggestion 
thanks

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to explain more clearly what your problem is. The reference site shows multiple markers on one google map - what more do you require?

Comment: yes..i need multiple marker in single google map.all marker will come from database. means all will dynamic.